# Ajax request cors and cookies steps

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, cors

I have a client front end at localhost:1841 and a back end at localhost:9000.

My authentication system use a simple couple username/password that delivers a Json Web Token(jwt).

When my client receives the token, i ask him to save it in the cookie with javascript. But when i make XmlhttpRequest call from my client (:1841) to my server (:9000), **there is no cookies in the request**. So my server delivers a 401 (behavior is ok). 
I know that is normal, none information from the cookies is sent because of the SAME-ORIGIN-POLICY.

I m using extjs 6 as client and node js as server.

**What are all the steps to configure in the server side and client side to make this working ?**

In server side i have already authorize cors request.
I have heard of httpOnly ? but i don't know how to deal with it?

Call for login from localhost:1841 (extjs client):

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/users/authenticate/',
        method: 'POST',
        params: params,
        success: function(response){
            var text = response.responseText;
            var data = Ext.decode(text, true);

            if(data.access_token){
                me.saveToken(data.access_token);
                me.createInterface();
            } else {
                if(data.message){
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Bummer", data.message);
                } else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Bummer", "Something went wrong.");
                }
            }
        },
```

Config for cors:

```
cors = require('cors');
...
...
... 
var whitelist = ['http://127.0.0.1:9000', 'http://localhost:8080', 'http://localhost:9000', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', 'http://localhost:1841', 'http://127.0.0.1:1841']
 var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
    var corsOptions;
     if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
        corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
    }else{
        corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
 }
    callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}
...

module.exports = function(app) {
....
app.use(cors(corsOptionsDelegate));

}
```

Other call from client:

```
Ext.ajax.request({
  url : 'http://localhost:9000/api/users/'
  method : 'POST'
  success: function(response){
        var text = response.responseText;
        var data = Ext.decode(text, true);
        ...
        ...
        }
    },
})
```

Validation from server:

```
function isAuthenticated() {
    return compose()
//     Validate jwt
        .use(function (req, res, next) {

            ....
            ....
            console.log(req.headers.authorization);


            validateJwt(req, res, function (err) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.inner.name);
                    if (err.inner.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
                        // client have to request token with his refresh_token
                        return next({"error":err.inner.name});
                    }
                }
                next();
            });

    })
    .use(function (req, res, next) {
        ....

        });
    });
```

**Edit 1:**

I have added **Set-Cookie** in node and Set-Cookie appears in response headers AND in preview cookies from DevTools.  But cookies is not set in browser.

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res, next){
    User.findOne({
        fullName: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {
    ....
        if (!user) {
            res.status(401).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'
            });
        } else {
            // Check if password matches

            if(user.authenticate(req.body.password)){
                var access_token = jwt.sign(user, config.secrets.session, {
                    expiresIn: 60 // in seconds
               });

               res.cookie('access_token',access_token);

               res.status(200).json({
                   "success": true,
                   "access_token" : access_token
                   //token: 'JWT ' + token
                   });
            }else{
              ....
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We can't see how you are making the Ajax request (or even tell if you are using `fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest`, JSONP or something else), so it is hard to tell what is wrong with it.

Comment: "When my client receives the token, i ask him to save it in the cookie." — Which origin are you setting the cookie for? Are you doing it with HTTP or with JS?

Comment: @Quentin code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you using ExtJS [Ajax](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Ajax.html) so you can use [defaultXhrHeader](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Ajax.html#cfg-defaultXhrHeader) property to sending token from client side to sever side.

> Firstly as you are calling authenticate request for getting token. Here you can use ExtJS [Cookies](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.util.Cookies.html) for [set](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.util.Cookies.html#method-set) and [get](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.util.Cookies.html#method-get) token or cookies.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
     url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/users/authenticate/',
     params: params,
     method: 'POST',
     success: function(response, opts) {
         var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText;);
         if (data.access_token) {
             //Set cookie in our client side using Utility class for setting/reading values from browser cookies. 
             Ext.util.Cookies.set('access_token', data.access_token);
         } else {
             if (data.message) {
                 Ext.Msg.alert("Bummer", data.message);
             } else {
                 Ext.Msg.alert("Bummer", "Something went wrong.");
             }
         }
     },
     failure: function(response, opts) {
         console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
     }
 });
```

> Now you need to pass same token [Ajax](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Ajax.html#configs) request using [defaultXhrHeader](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Ajax.html#cfg-defaultXhrHeader)

Here is example:-

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
     url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/users/',
     method: 'POST', //As per method acceptance you can use (GET,PUT,DELETE).
     //send cookie sever side using defaultXhrHeader 
     defaultHeaders: {
         'access_token': Ext.util.Cookies.get('access_token'),
         'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
     },
     success: function(response, opts) {
         var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText;);
         //Put your logic here.
     },
     failure: function(response, opts) {
         console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
     }
 });
```

> As you using NodeJs in server side so you can get token from header.

Comment: Your example is exactly what i tested before (with the ext.set cookies) but because of the same origin policy (server is localhost:9000 and client is:1841) all my others ajax request cannot have access to the cookies and cannot send the access_token, so i used localStorage instead of cookies.
what i whant is to save securely "access_token" in cookies with httpOnly and secure flag.

Comment: can you please try with `Ext.Ajax.useDefaultXhrHeader = false;` and        `Ext.Ajax.cors = true;` hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side JavaScript can only set cookies for the current origin.

Other origins will have their own set of cookies.

You will need to either:

- Set the cookie from the :9000 origin using HTTP *or*
- Pass the data through some other mechanism (such as a value in a POST body).

Comment: You mean that i have to set a cookie with "Set-cookie" from :9000 and to put httpOnly flag?

Comment: It doesn't have to be httpOnly, but if you want to send it to :9000 then you have to set it from :9000

Comment: Set-Cookie added in server side , cookie present in response but not saved in browser.

Comment: _"but not saved in browser"_ - are you checking under the right origin? Your browser is likely to consider this a 3rd-party cookie (_because_ of its different origin), so check your settings regarding those, and whether any privacy extension might be eating them.

Comment: Plus, since this is a cross-domain request, the cookie will only be _send back_ with the next request to the port `:9000` origin, if the pre-flight request is handled properly by your server-side (`OPTIONS` request, needs to be answered with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header containing the exact origin you are making the request from, `http://what.ever:1841`, basically the exact content of the `Origin` request header. `*` won't do, that will block all credentials [HTTP Auth, cookies, etc.] from being send with the _actual_ request in the first place.)

Comment: CBroe this is exaclty what does my config for cors. Origin is tested when request is serverside and the header is correctly set